# Mongoose Model.find is not a function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Spent hours trying to figure this out - I'm adding a new Model to my app but it's failing with "TypeError: List.find is not a function".  I have another model, Items, that is set up in the same way and is working fine.  Things seem to be failing in the route but it works if I hook it up to the Item model.  Am I declaring the Schema incorrectly?  Do I need to init the model in mongo or something?

model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var listSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, default: datestring + " List" }
});

mongoose.exports = mongoose.model('List', listSchema);
```

route

```
app.get('/lists', function (req, res, err) {
    List.find(function (err, docs){ //THIS IS WHAT'S FAILING
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

controller

```
angular.module('pickUp').controller('ListsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'ngDialog', 'lists',

        function($scope, $http, ngDialog, lists) {

        $scope.lists = lists.lists;

    }]);
```

factory

```
angular.module('pickUp').factory('lists', ['$http',
    function($http){

        var lists = {
            lists: []
        };

        lists.getAll = function(){
            console.log("trying. . .");
            $http.get('/lists').success(function(res){
                angular.copy(res, lists.lists);
            });
        };

        return lists;
}]);
```

config

```
$stateProvider
.state('/', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'views/lists.html',
    controller: 'ListsCtrl',
    resolve: {
        listPromise: ['lists', function (lists){
            return lists.getAll();
        }]
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your module export is incorrect

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var listSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, default: datestring + " List" }
});

**mongoose.exports = mongoose.model('List', listSchema);** <!-- this is wrong -->
```

it should be

```
**module.exports = mongoose.model('List', listSchema)**
```

Comment: i do exactly as you suggest, but same error occurred.

Answer (score 10):

i faced this issue . to solve this , you need to understand one logic .
you need to call `.find` as promise to model which is imported from models file.

example:

```
const member = require('..// path to model')

//model initiation
const Member = new member();

exports.searchMembers = function (req,res) {


Member.find({},(err,docs)=>{
    res.status(200).json(docs)
})

}
```

this code dont work because i called `find()` to initiated schema

code that works :

```
exports.searchMembers = function (req,res) {


member.find({},(err,docs)=>{
    res.status(200).json(docs)
})

}
```

here i called `.find()` directly to imported model

Answer (score 1):

You've defined incorrect module.exports.

`mongoose.exports = mongoose.model('List', listSchema);`

This should be

`module.exports = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);`

Answer (score 0):

To import model instance and call method, for example

**modelfile.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const NotificationSchema = new Schema({
    count: Number,
    color: String,
    icon: String,
    name: String,
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
    read: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('notifications', NotificationSchema);
```

**queryfile.js**

```
const Notification = require('./models/model-notifications');

function totalInsert(online) {
  let query = { name: 'viewed count' };
  Notification.find(query,(err,result)=>{
    if(!err){
      totalCount.count = online + result.length;
      totalCount.save((err,result)=>{
        if(!err){
          io.emit('total visitor', totalCount);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have exported your Model/Schema correctly.

```
module.exports = User
```

After this above step make sure to require the Model/Schema.js file in your index.js(Main Route File)

```
const Task = require('./models/task')
```

Below are some snippets for the explanation. All the best.!

[image]

[image]