# mongodb - find() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I want to print all documents of "members" collection. I used `find()` function but it throw error : `find() is not a function`.

In member_model.js (in models/admin folder):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var MemberSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('members', MemberSchema);
```

In index.js (in controllers/admin folder):

```
const members = require('../../models/admin/member_model');
var Members = new members();
Members.find({}, function (err, resDB) {
  assert.equal(err,null);
  console.log(json(resDB));
});
```

I checked connecting to DB, it's still ok.
I also read some other questions but any suitable answer for my problem.

Note more i tested like this :

In auth.js (in controllers/admin folder):

```
const members = require('../../models/admin/member_model');
var Members = new members();
Members.username = req.body.username;
Members.password = req.body.password;
var refererURL = req.headers.referer;

Members.save((err, resSave) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.redirect(refererURL);
  } else {
    console.log('saved');
  }
})

Members.find({}, function (err, resDB) {
  assert.equal(err,null);
  console.log(json(resDB));
});
```

`Members.save()` is ok, but `Members.find()` still error.

Help me what my error is ?
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like `members` might not be importing correctly

Comment: const members = require('../../models/admin/member_model');Is this line ?

Comment: yep. have you tried checking whats stored in Members?

Comment: I have just edited my question more details. Please help me check it !

Comment: check ur module.export in a file where u have written your schema for member collection or update your question with schema file

Comment: Ok Sam, i have updated question with schema file.

Comment: i answered this here . [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49486901/8219568) hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code:

In **member_model.js** (in models/admin folder):

Change the below code to :

```
// module.exports = mongoose.model('members', MemberSchema);
module.exports = {
  memberCollection: mongoose.model('members', MemberSchema)
}
```

In **index.js** (in controllers/admin folder):

```
const members = require('../../models/admin/member_model');
members.memberCollection.find({}, function (err, resDB) {
  assert.equal(err,null);
  console.log(json(resDB));
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ti2005 ! I found it but your answer help me save my time!

Comment: Why adding  moogoose.model inside an object make it works??